# Not able to send email using PHP

Tags: php, smtp

I have a simple PHP form with few fields and form details are sent using following code mentioned below..

Even thought i get "Thank you. Your messsage has been received." message but message never comes through.

I tried changed  `$use_smtp = '0';` still doesn't work

```
 <?php
include('SMTPClass.php');

$use_smtp = '1';
$emailto = 'info@domain.com';

    // retrieve from parameters
    $emailfrom = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
    $nocomment = isset($_POST["nocomment"]) ? $_POST["nocomment"] : "";
    $subject = 'Email from Website';
    $message = '';
    $response = 'Thank you for your message. I will be in contact shortly.';
    $response_fail = 'There was an error verifying your details.';

        // Honeypot captcha
        if($nocomment == "") {

            $params = $_POST;
            foreach ( $params as $key=>$value ){

                if(!($key == 'ip' || $key == 'emailsubject' || $key == 'url' || $key == 'emailto' || $key == 'nocomment' || $key == 'v_error' || $key == 'v_email')){

                    $key = ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $key));

                    if ( gettype( $value ) == "array" ){
                        $message .= "$key: \n";
                        foreach ( $value as $two_dim_value )
                        $message .= "...$two_dim_value<br>";
                    }else {
                        $message .= $value != '' ? "$key: $value\n" : '';
                    }
                }
            }

        $response = sendEmail($subject, $message, $emailto, $emailfrom);

        } else {

            $response = $response_fail;

        }

    echo $response;

// Run server-side validation
function sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom) {

    $from = $emailfrom;
    $response_sent = 'Thank you. Your messsage has been received.';
    $response_error = 'Error. Please try again.';
    $subject =  filter($subject);
    $url = "Origin Page: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $ip = "IP Address: ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $message = $content."\n$ip\r\n$url";

    // Validate return email & inform admin
    $emailto = filter($emailto);

    // Setup final message
    $body = wordwrap($message);

    if($use_smtp == '1'){

        $SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $SmtpPort = '587';
        $SmtpUser = 'no-reply@domain.com';
        $SmtpPass = 'password';

        $to = $emailto;
        $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
        $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
        $response = $SMTPChat ? $response_sent : $response_error;

    } else {

        // Create header
        $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";

        // Send email
        $mail_sent = @mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $response = $mail_sent ? $response_sent : $response_error;

    }
    return $response;
}

// Remove any un-safe values to prevent email injection
function filter($value) {
    $pattern = array("/\n/", "/\r/", "/content-type:/i", "/to:/i", "/from:/i", "/cc:/i");
    $value = preg_replace($pattern, "", $value);
    return $value;
}

exit;

?>
```

Comment: A true return value of `mail` means that the mail server received and accepted the mail. It does not mean the mail was sent or the target mail server accepted it. That's all what you can check for. You may need to check the mail server.

Comment: Is this not the right way of sending email as i am authenticating it with credentials.. or should i take a different approach

Comment: If you use SMTP you need to authenticate with credientials of course.

Comment: That is my point if i am authenticating then why it fails using PHP and works with .Net

Comment: Do you get an error? If you get a success, check the mail server. If you dont have access, ask mail server admin for assistance

Comment: May be it is not going through as `Encryption method: TLS` is not mentioned. Not sure how to add this is PHP

Answer (score 2):

This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps